# Which matplotlib methods may be called outside the GUI thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, wxpython

I've read that matplotlib is not generally thread safe. So let's assume proper synchronization. I've also come across the following statement in a matplotlib-users discussion:

> all GUI stuff must happen on the main thread (if you do threads), but
>   for some backends `draw_idle()` maybe thread safe.

(thanks @tacaswell)

But which methods are considered "GUI stuff" and which backends are thread safe for `draw_idle()`?

Consider a trivial matplotlib + wxpython phoenix example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from threading import Thread

import numpy as np
import wx
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as Canvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = wx.Panel(frame)

figure = Figure()
canvas = Canvas(panel, wx.ID_ANY, figure)

def slow():
    figure.gca().imshow(np.random.randn(5_000, 5_000))
    canvas.draw_idle()

button = wx.Button(panel, label='Go')
button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event: Thread(target=slow).start())

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
panel.SetSizer(sizer)

frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I'm calling both `imshow()` and `draw_idle()` from outside the GUI thread and it seems to work fine.

If I repeat this approach throughout a real world application am I going to run into trouble? Is it necessary to move either of these method calls into the GUI thread? If not, is `draw_idle()` in fact thread safe under wxpython or will it require synchronization?